# How to do a git fetch in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do not see an option to do a git fetch inside vscode Source Control tab.

How can I check what origin remote codes am I pulling and merging into my local source codes?

Comment: Why can't you just use the terminal for `git fetch`?

Comment: so there is no support for this in vs code? got it!

Comment: @ifconfig how do you view the incoming changes? I did a git fetch and it just says it "found x objects to send. unpacking objects.. done." but it doesn't highlight the files or what was changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VScode has a setting "git.autofetch" that is enabled to be true by default. This means when you do a git pull from the ... menu, a fetch will be ran prior to the pull. If you set git.autofetch to false, there is no explicit command from the dropdown that will do a fetch for you. You would have to type it in manually.

Comment: git.autofetch enables VS Code "to periodically fetch changes from your remotes." The git pull command will always perform a git fetch; it has nothing to do with the git.autofetch setting inside VS Code. "Starting with VS Code 1.19, this feature is disabled by default."

Comment: who needs this fetch anyways, it doesnt do anything

Comment: Why is this flagged as the correct answer, when there _is_ an explicit git fetch, as noted in the answer that was posted 6 years before this one?

Comment: @monstro `git fetch` loads newly created remote branches. I use this a lot to switch to gitlab feature branches. And in that case I usually don't want to pull changes into my current branch just to switch to the feature branch.

Comment: @monstro If you want to get the list of remote branches to switch to one of them, `git fetch` refreshes the list. I don't know if there is any command which does it.

Comment: What @CalebBergman and@Mike said - this is not a correct answer. @Monstro I find autofetch really useful - I often use git from the terminal and when I do `git status` it will tell me if there are upstream commits.

Comment: the actual correct answer is below from @Willem - use the command palette to fetch

Comment: How do I see the fetch changed items?  Is there a way to have a "Fetch" section like you have the "modified"?

Comment: default seems to have changed to `false`.

Answer (score 59):

In View -> Command Palette... you can find many other git commands, including Fetch.

Answer (score 4):

VSCode 1.67 (Apr. 2022) will make that command more visible with a new menu entry.
(located, as noted by [Kilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175290/kilo) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600136/how-to-do-a-git-fetch-in-vscode/71755438?noredirect=1#comment128584181_71755438), within the "`...`" menu in the `Source Control` area.)
See [issue 137916](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137916) and [PR 137940](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/137940):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1876302/143589889-7a68671e-b77e-44fe-990c-01f35e27d659.png]

The command palette is no longer the only option to find this Git operation.

Comment: (yes, and it's located within the "..." menu in the Source Control area.)

Comment: @Kilo Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

One alternate way is :

Go to `SOURCE CONTROL` Tab -> go to `REMOTES` section and you will be presented with the remote origin and there you have a **reload button** which also runs git fetch command.