# Need to take latest/updated code from master to my local branch- GH6789/learninggit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

I am not sure which command I can use for taking latest code from master to my local branch. My local branch is GH6789/learninggit. I need to take pull on VS Code. Can someone help/suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would not merge master to a branch, but rather rebase that branch on top of origin/master, which means, on VSCode:

- [fetching the remote origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50298273/6309) (it should be done automatically anyway)
- [rebasing your current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51409189/6309) (choosing the origin/master branch as new upstream)